# Does a .json API need to be secure (https) to be used in iOS app development?

Tags: ios

I am building my first app using an api (http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json). It doesn't support https will this prevent me from a successful submission in the iOS app store?

Comment: Even if it is possible; don't. Get https up and running.

Comment: Yes, Apple has announced that they will require apps to use App Transport Security (ATS). ATS requires to use of TLS1.2 or newer. This would have been a requirement from januari, for now Apple has delayed this requirement but will require it in the furture.

Comment: Using non secure connections, especially with an api, is vulnerable for data leaks. Not only you app's data is vulnerable, also session token of users and even user information. If you think this won't happen; check the free wifi-points in a hotel lounge ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The App Transport Security forces you to use HTTPS. You could define exceptions, but Apple will automatically reject your app unless you've contacted Apple and provided a detailed explanation, why you can't use HTTPS.

See [Session 706](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/) of the WWDC 2016 for more information. [This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979) in the Developer Forums may contain some useful information for you, too.

---

I would strongly recommend you to set up HTTPS on your server. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) provides you the possibility to get certificates for free.

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL instead of open-notify

https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/SSapplications/Post/JavaSSOP/orbit/ISS/SVPOST.html

and use HTML Parsing for parsing the data